# Dictionary returning a default value if the key does not exist

Tags: c#, collections, dictionary

I find myself using the current pattern quite often in my code nowadays

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<type, IList<othertype>>();
// Add stuff to dictionary

var somethingElse = dictionary.ContainsKey(key) ? dictionary[key] : new List<othertype>();
// Do work with the somethingelse variable
```

Or sometimes

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<type, IList<othertype>>();
// Add stuff to dictionary

IList<othertype> somethingElse;
if(!dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out somethingElse) {
    somethingElse = new List<othertype>();
}
```

Both of these ways feel quite roundabout. What I really would like is something like

```
dictionary.GetValueOrDefault(key)
```

Now, I could write an extension method for the dictionary class that does this for me, but I figured that I might be missing something that already exists. SO, is there a way to do this in a way that is more "easy on the eyes" without writing an extension method to dictionary?

Comment: Not sure why all the below answers are so complex. Just use the coalescing operator: `string valFromDict = someDict["someKey"] ?? "someDefaultVal";`

Comment: @DylanHunt That doesnt work for value types though. ;)

Comment: Also note that using the `[]` operator also has the possibly unwanted side effect of adding a value to the dictionary if one doesn't exist.

Comment: Since this is still the top question when googling this, really key for folks to check out the linked answer. This feature has [existed for years](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.collectionextensions.getvalueordefault?view=net-7.0#system-collections-generic-collectionextensions-getvalueordefault-2(system-collections-generic-ireadonlydictionary((-0-1))-0-1))

Comment: @dataprincess GetValueOrDefault() could be nice to just say what it is instead of an external link btw this is what exactly the OP asked. TryGetValue in accepted answer is not a one liner, it just returns boolean, until it was edited for the comments though

Answer (score 374, accepted):

---

As per comments, in .Net Core 2+ / NetStandard 2.1+ / Net 5, [MS added the extension method GetValueOrDefault()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.collectionextensions.getvalueordefault?view=netstandard-2.1)

---

`TryGetValue` will already assign the default value for the type to the dictionary, so you can just use:

```
dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
```

and just ignore the return value. However, that really *will* just return `default(TValue)`, not some custom default value (nor, more usefully, the result of executing a delegate). There's nothing more powerful built into the framework. I would suggest two extension methods:

```
public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(
    this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary,
    TKey key,
    TValue defaultValue)
{
    return dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var value) ? value : defaultValue;
}

public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(
    this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary,
    TKey key,
    Func<TValue> defaultValueProvider)
{
    return dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var value) ? value : defaultValueProvider();
}
```

(You may want to put argument checking in, of course :)

Comment: To open a can of worms, these extensions work when key doesn't exist, but TryGetValue throws if key is null. Knowing whether key is nullable or not would make this a trivial check.

Comment: @ProfK: You can just compare the key with `null` anyway; when TKey is a non-nullable value type, it will just always return false. Personally I don't think I'd want to do that though - null keys *almost* always represent a bug, in my experience.

Comment: They do. Just as soon as I tried your code, the crappy data I'm dealing with presented a null key, but I can't change that now.

Comment: @ProfK: Right - it makes sense to change the code for your particular case then, but I wouldn't want to propose it in general :)

Comment: Thanks for this.  How about a default value for 3rd arg?  TValue defaultValue = default(TValue)

Comment: This extension method by the way also enables using TryGetValue against a dictionary (created by LINQ) where the value type is an anonymous type.

Comment: Given Jon's answer I was stuck on how to actually call his extension methods (having never done that before) and so I stumbled across this MS article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311042.aspx.

Comment: In later versions you can use System.Collections.Generic which provides GetValueOrDefault(key, defaultValue).

Answer (score 31):

I do favor extension methods, but here's a simple class I use from time to time to handle dictionaries when I need default values.

I wish this were just part of the base Dictionary class.

```
public class DictionaryWithDefault<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
  TValue _default;
  public TValue DefaultValue {
    get { return _default; }
    set { _default = value; }
  }
  public DictionaryWithDefault() : base() { }
  public DictionaryWithDefault(TValue defaultValue) : base() {
    _default = defaultValue;
  }
  public new TValue this[TKey key]
  {
    get { 
      TValue t;
      return base.TryGetValue(key, out t) ? t : _default;
    }
    set { base[key] = value; }
  }
}
```

Beware, however. By subclassing and using `new` (since `override` is not available on the native `Dictionary` type), if a `DictionaryWithDefault` object is upcast to a plain `Dictionary`, calling the indexer will use the base `Dictionary` implementation (throwing an exception if missing) rather than the subclass's implementation.

Comment: Use trygetvalue better..

Comment: trygetvalue doesn't allow you to specify a default value, ie for a string value you may want it to return "" instead of null

Comment: @nawfal TryGetValue has be used every time I ask for a value in the dictionary. This simple wrapper means that I can just ask for a value and it will either return the value or the default I specified in the constructor. I don't have to remember to use a special method.

Comment: @roberocity No, I meant use `TryGetValue` inside your indexer (instead of `base.ContainsKey(key) ? base[key]`)

Comment: @Katbyte see my comment above.

Comment: @nawfal. Ahh. Ok. Is that a personal preference or is there a bit of a performance boost?

Comment: @roberocity yes a performance advantage, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382681/what-is-more-efficient-dictionary-trygetvalue-or-containskeyitem

Comment: There is a bug in the above code. It will always return 0 as default value, because TryGetValue sets "t" to 0.
Change to;
    TValue t;
    if (!TryGetValue(key, out t))
    {
     t = m_default;
    }
    return t;

Comment: I think it is ill-advised to inherit from `Dictionary` in this case: by using the `new` keyword you are hiding the non-virtual `Item` property. If someone was to access it from a `Dictionary` reference type, and not a `DictionaryWithDefault`, it is `Dictionary`'s `Item` property that would be called, not yours.

Comment: The ctor that uses `TValue defaultValue` seems of little value.  The only time I can see using a specific value instead of `default(TValue)`  is when TValue is a string, and you want the default to be `String.Empty`.  In far more cases, you'd want the default to be `new TValue()` --- but you can't pass that to the ctor as it would assign the same object to each new entry.  My idea would be a ctor taking a bool, (which defaults to false).  if true, `new TValue()`.  Unfortunately, that would require a `with TValue : new()` qualifier, which would preclude using string as a TValue.

Comment: Instead of subclassing `Dictionary<,>` it's possible to have an underlying `Dictionary<,>` - or even better `IDictionary<,>` - and delegate everything to it (with the sole exception of a custom getter for `this[]` that handles returning the default value in case the underlying dictionary doesn't contain the key). It's more code, but cleaner and more flexible.

Comment: If you want to implement it by yourself you can create a simple Extension Method instead of building your own class

Answer (score 25):

I created a [DefaultableDictionary](https://github.com/jsonmez/Defaultable-Dictionary) to do exactly what you are asking for!

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace DefaultableDictionary {
    public class DefaultableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue> {
        private readonly IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary;
        private readonly TValue defaultValue;

        public DefaultableDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TValue defaultValue) {
            this.dictionary = dictionary;
            this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
        }

        public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator() {
            return dictionary.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }

        public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item) {
            dictionary.Add(item);
        }

        public void Clear() {
            dictionary.Clear();
        }

        public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item) {
            return dictionary.Contains(item);
        }

        public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex) {
            dictionary.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
        }

        public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item) {
            return dictionary.Remove(item);
        }

        public int Count {
            get { return dictionary.Count; }
        }

        public bool IsReadOnly {
            get { return dictionary.IsReadOnly; }
        }

        public bool ContainsKey(TKey key) {
            return dictionary.ContainsKey(key);
        }

        public void Add(TKey key, TValue value) {
            dictionary.Add(key, value);
        }

        public bool Remove(TKey key) {
            return dictionary.Remove(key);
        }

        public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value) {
            if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value)) {
                value = defaultValue;
            }

            return true;
        }

        public TValue this[TKey key] {
            get
            {
                try
                {
                    return dictionary[key];
                } catch (KeyNotFoundException) {
                    return defaultValue;
                }
            }

            set { dictionary[key] = value; }
        }

        public ICollection<TKey> Keys {
            get { return dictionary.Keys; }
        }

        public ICollection<TValue> Values {
            get
            {
                var values = new List<TValue>(dictionary.Values) {
                    defaultValue
                };
                return values;
            }
        }
    }

    public static class DefaultableDictionaryExtensions {
        public static IDictionary<TKey, TValue> WithDefaultValue<TValue, TKey>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TValue defaultValue ) {
            return new DefaultableDictionary<TKey, TValue>(dictionary, defaultValue);
        }
    }
}
```

This project is a simple decorator for an IDictionary object and an extension method to make it easy to use.

The DefaultableDictionary will allow for creating a wrapper around a dictionary that provides a default value when trying to access a key that does not exist or enumerating through all the values in an IDictionary.

Example: `var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>().WithDefaultValue(5);`

[Blog post](http://simpleprogrammer.com/2011/08/14/making-switch-refactorings-better-defaultable-dictionary/) on the usage as well.

Comment: Please provide the context supporting the github link directly in your answer, or it will likely be removed.

Comment: Would be helpful if you didn't delete the links that provided clarity as well.

Comment: I'd write the index getter as:
`public TValue this[TKey key] {
       get
       {
  TValue value;
  TryGetValue(key, out value);
  return value;
       }` 
To avoid the exception handling.

Comment: I like that you used an extension method to create the default dictionary instead of requiring your constructor be used (as I did).

Comment: Exception-based flow control... yikers! That's a serious anti-pattern. Please change your indexer implementation to use `TryGetValue` instead of `try ... catch`.

Comment: It is also important to convert `TValue value` into `Func<TValue> value`. And indexer should add a value to dictionary if it was not found. Otherwise  you will have problems if you would want to populate dictionary with reference types. This: `var dict = new DefaultDictionary<string, List<int>>(emptyDict, new List<int>()); dict["hello"].Add(3);` won't work

Comment: This seems so much overkill just to get a default value for non-existing keys.

Comment: If you want to implement it by yourself you can create a simple Extension Method instead of building your own class

Comment: This looks like the kind of a thing that gets discovered while trying to figure out a performance issue.

Answer (score 7):

No, nothing like that exists.  The extension method is the way to go, and your name for it (*GetValueOrDefault*) is a pretty good choice.