# What is more efficient: Dictionary TryGetValue or ContainsKey+Item?

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary

From MSDN's entry on [Dictionary.TryGetValue Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx):

> This method combines the functionality of the ContainsKey method and
>   the Item property.
>
> If the key is not found, then the value parameter gets the appropriate
>   default value for the value type TValue; for example, 0 (zero) for
>   integer types, false for Boolean types, and null for reference types.
>
> Use the TryGetValue method if your code frequently attempts to access
>   keys that are not in the dictionary. Using this method is more
>   efficient than catching the KeyNotFoundException thrown by the Item
>   property.
>
> This method approaches an O(1) operation.

From the description, it's not clear if it is more efficient or just more convenient than calling ContainsKey and then doing the lookup. Does the implementation of `TryGetValue` just call ContainsKey and then Item or is actually more efficient than that by doing a single lookup?

In other words, what is more efficient (i.e. which one performs less lookups):

```
Dictionary<int,int> dict;
//...//
int ival;
if(dict.ContainsKey(ikey))
{
  ival = dict[ikey];
}
else
{
  ival = default(int);
}
```

or

```
Dictionary<int,int> dict;
//...//
int ival;
dict.TryGetValue(ikey, out ival);
```

Note: I am not looking for a benchmark!

Answer (score 411, accepted):

`TryGetValue` will be faster.

`ContainsKey` uses the same check as `TryGetValue`, which internally refers to the actual entry location.  The `Item` property actually has nearly identical code functionality as `TryGetValue`, except that it will throw an exception instead of returning false.

Using `ContainsKey` followed by the `Item` basically duplicates the lookup functionality, which is the bulk of the computation in this case.

Comment: This is more subtle: `if(dict.ContainsKey(ikey))  dict[ikey]++;
else
 dict.Add(ikey, 0);`. But i think that `TryGetValue` is still more efficient since the get *and* set of the indexer property is used, isn't it?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes - The ContainsKey and the accessor both do the checks - if you used TryGetValue, you'd only be doing the `get` work once, effectively, instead of twice.

Comment: you can actually look at the .net source for it now too: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,2e5bc6d8c0f21e67  you can see that all 3 of TryGetValue, ContainsKey, and this[] call the same FindEntry method and do the same amount of work, only differing in how they answer the question: trygetvalue returns bool and the value, contains key only returns true/false, and this[] returns the value or throws an exception.

Comment: @JohnGardner Yes, which is what I said - but if you do ContainsKey then get Item, you're doing that work 2x instead of 1x.

Comment: i agree completely :)  i was just pointing out that the actual source is available now.  none of the other answers/etc had a link to the actual source :D

Comment: Slightly off topic, if you're accessing via an IDictionary in a multithreaded environment I would always use TryGetValue as the state may change from the time you call ContainsKey (there's no guarantee that TryGetValue will internally lock correctly either, but it's probably safer)

Answer (score 105):

A quick benchmark shows that `TryGetValue` has a slight edge:

```
    static void Main() {
        var d = new Dictionary<string, string> {{"a", "b"}};
        var start = DateTime.Now;
        for (int i = 0; i != 10000000; i++) {
            string x;
            if (!d.TryGetValue("a", out x)) throw new ApplicationException("Oops");
            if (d.TryGetValue("b", out x)) throw new ApplicationException("Oops");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now-start);
        start = DateTime.Now;
        for (int i = 0; i != 10000000; i++) {
            string x;
            if (d.ContainsKey("a")) {
                x = d["a"];
            } else {
                x = default(string);
            }
            if (d.ContainsKey("b")) {
                x = d["b"];
            } else {
                x = default(string);
            }
        }
   }
```

This produces

```
00:00:00.7600000
00:00:01.0610000
```

making the `ContainsKey + Item` access about 40% slower assuming an even blend of hits and misses.

Moreover, when I change the program to always miss (i.e. always looking up `"b"`) the two versions become equally fast:

```
00:00:00.2850000
00:00:00.2720000
```

When I make it "all hits", however, the `TryGetValue` remains a clear winner:

```
00:00:00.4930000
00:00:00.8110000
```

Comment: I added a test case using Linq (Any()) instead of ContainsKey() and it ran about 3 times slower. So, between TryGetValue, ConstainsKey, and Linq Any(), stay away from "Linq Any()".

Comment: @Luciano explain how you used `Any` - Like this: `Any(i=>i.Key==key)`. In which case, yes, that's a bad linear search of the dictionary.

Comment: @weston: Yep ! `Any(i => i.Key == key)`

Comment: `DateTime.Now` will only be accurate to a few ms. Use the `Stopwatch` class in `System.Diagnostics` instead (which uses QueryPerformanceCounter under the covers to provide much higher accuracy). It's easier to use, too.

Comment: In addition to Alastair and Ed's comments - DateTime.Now can go backwards, if you get a time update, such as that which occurs when the user updates their computer time, a time zone is crossed, or the time zone changes (DST, for instance). Try working on a system that has the system clock synced to time provided by some radio service like GPS or mobile phone networks. DateTime.Now will go all over the place, and DateTime.UtcNow only fixes one of those causes. Just use StopWatch.

Comment: I would not expect a test on a dictionary with only 2 entries to match real-world conditions :/

Comment: This is not a useful test. You need to add more than a single key/value pair to the dictionary before running your benchmark (otherwise O(1) and O(n) are equal and your results are off by a factor of n). Try generating a few hundred or few thousand pairs and running this again.

Comment: @Dan Both operations I am comparing are required to be O(1), this is not the point of the benchmark.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You can't test a single iteration of something timed in milliseconds and expect to get useful results. There's a reason every other benchmark answer on this page iterates over the operation a bunch of times to get realistic averages. Also, as Ed S. pointed out, DateTime is not a good sub-second timer for performance testing. Use the built-in performance timer: `System.Diagnostics.StopWatch` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Dan My benchmark also iterates over the operation ten million times to get realistic results. Moreover, my results are very much in line with what everyone else is getting: for example, 45/26 ratio of davisoa is within 5% of my 0.811/0.493 ratio.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Ah, I was admittedly slightly confused by the "Moreover, when I change the program..." part that isn't shown in the code. It helps if your code snippet matches your sample output (I'm assuming you just commented "a" and "b" parts for the other tests?). Nevertheless, a million iterations over a Dictionary with one element still seems kind of silly, but if you're sure that's what you were testing; so be it!

Comment: "a million iterations over a Dictionary with one element still seems kind of silly" -- only to the completely clueless. This is not a benchmark of the hashtable implementation. If that implementation happens to be particularly bad, then adding a bunch of entries to the table may unduly disadvantage ContainsKey+d[]. By using the simplest case, the benchmark gets at what it wants to measure and not what it doesn't.

Answer (score 64):

Since none of the answers thus far actually answer the question, here is an acceptable answer I found after some research:

If you decompile TryGetValue you see that it’s doing this:

```
public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
{
  int index = this.FindEntry(key);
  if (index >= 0)
  {
    value = this.entries[index].value;
    return true;
  }
  value = default(TValue);
  return false;
}
```

whereas the ContainsKey method is:

```
public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
{
  return (this.FindEntry(key) >= 0);
}
```

so TryGetValue is just ContainsKey plus an array lookup if the item is present.

[Source](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/840)

It appears that TryGetValue will be almost twice as fast as ContainsKey+Item combination.

Comment: if there is not matching key, ContainsKey does not need to access to any Item[].

Answer (score 20):

Who cares :-)

You're probably asking because `TryGetValue` is a pain to use - so encapsulate it like this with an extension method.

```
public static class CollectionUtils
{
    // my original method
    // public static V GetValueOrDefault<K, V>(this Dictionary<K, V> dic, K key)
    // {
    //    V ret;
    //    bool found = dic.TryGetValue(key, out ret);
    //    if (found)
    //    {
    //        return ret;
    //    }
    //    return default(V);
    // }


    // EDIT: one of many possible improved versions
    public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<K, V>(this IDictionary<K, V> dictionary, K key)
    {
        // initialized to default value (such as 0 or null depending upon type of TValue)
        TValue value;  

        // attempt to get the value of the key from the dictionary
        dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
        return value;
    }
```

Then just call :

```
dict.GetValueOrDefault("keyname")
```

or

```
(dict.GetValueOrDefault("keyname") ?? fallbackValue)
```

Comment: @Hüseyin I got very confused how I was stupid enough to post this without `this` but it turns out I have my method duplicated twice in my code base - once with and one without the `this` so that's why I never caught it! thanks for fixing!

Comment: `TryGetValue` assigns a default value to the out value parameter if the key doesnt exist, so this could be simplified.

Comment: Simplified version:

public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey key)
        {
            TValue ret;
            dict.TryGetValue(key, out ret);
            return ret;
        }

Comment: In C#7 this is really fun: `if(!dic.TryGetValue(key, out value item)) item = dic[key] = new Item();`

Comment: This could confuse even more people at your company, now they will have 3 options `TryGetValue`, `ContainsKey`, or `GetValueOrDefault`

Comment: @Jaider it's just me :) plus i just cannot stand TryGetValue. Its clumsiness is just obtuse - admittedly made marginally better by the new ability to define an out parameter in place.

Comment: Note that users of this extension method can't tell the difference between a non-existent key and a key that exists but its value is the default value.

Comment: Ironically, the real source code already HAS a GetValueOrDefault() routine, but it's hidden... 
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,9680ab8ad8dfbf8d

Comment: UPDATE for C# 7: `TryGetValue` is now less burdensome, because the `out` param can be inlined: `if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out TValue value) ... else ...`. For situations where you want special code on either of the `if` branches, this may be (slightly) more concise than using this answer's `GetValueOrDefault`.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve yes definitely when you have an of statement that is better. About 9 times out of 10 that I need to get a value I want to use it immediately.

Answer (score 11):

Why don't you test it?

But I'm pretty sure that `TryGetValue` is faster, because it only does one lookup. Of course this isn't guaranteed, i.e. different implementations might have different performance characteristics.

The way I'd implement a dictionary is by creating an internal `Find` function that finds the slot for an item, and then build the rest on top of that.

Comment: I don't think the implementation details can possibly change the guarantee that doing action X once is faster than or equal to doing action X twice. Best case they're identical, worse case the 2X version takes twice as long.

Answer (score 10):

All of the answers so far, although good, miss a vital point.

Methods into the classes of an API (e.g. the .NET framework) form part of an interface definition (not a C# or VB interface, but an interface in the computer science meaning).

As such, it is usually incorrect to ask whether calling such a method is faster, unless speed is a part of the formal interface definition (which it isn't in this case).

Traditionally this kind of shortcut (combining search and retrieve) is more efficient regardless of language, infrastructure, OS, platform, or machine architecture. It is also more readable, because it expresses your intent explicitly, rather than implying it (from the structure of your code).

So the answer (from a grizzled old hack) is definitely 'Yes' (TryGetValue is preferable to a combination of ContainsKey and Item [Get] to retrieve a value from a Dictionary).

If you think this sounds odd, think of it like this: Even if current implementations of TryGetValue, ContainsKey, and Item [Get] do not yield any speed difference, you can assume it is likely that a future implementation (e.g. .NET v5) will do (TryGetValue will be faster). Think about the lifetime of your software.

As an aside, it is interesting to note that typical modern interface definition technologies still rarely provide any means of formally defining timing constraints. Maybe .NET v5?

Comment: While I 100% agree with your argument about semantics, it is still worth doing the performance test. You never know when the API you're using has a suboptimal implementation such that the semantically correct thing happens to be slower, unless you do the test.

Answer (score 8):

Apart from designing a microbenchmark that will give accurate results in a practical setting, you can inspect the reference source of .NET Framework.

- [`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.TryGetValue(TKey, out TValue)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,2e5bc6d8c0f21e67)
- [`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ContainsKey(TKey)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,22fd7cd7408aed6e)
- [`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.Item(TKey)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,49962975508e2d83)

All of them call the [`FindEntry(TKey)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,bcd13bb775d408f1) method that does most of the work and does not memoize its result, so **calling `TryGetValue` is almost twice as fast as `ContainsKey` + `Item`**.

---

The inconvenient interface of **`TryGetValue`** can be **adapted using an extension method**:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Project.Common.Extensions
{
    public static class DictionaryExtensions
    {
        public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(
            this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary,
            TKey key,
            TValue defaultValue = default(TValue))
        {
            if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out TValue value))
            {
                return value;
            }
            return defaultValue;
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>Since C# 7.1, you can replace `default(TValue)` with plain `default`. [The type is inferred.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/default-value-expressions#default-literal-and-type-inference)</sup>

Usage:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string val = dict.GetValueOrDefault("theKey", "value used if theKey is not found in dict");
```

It returns `null` for reference types whose lookup fails, unless an explicit default value is specified.

```
var dictObj = new Dictionary<string, object>();
object valObj = dictObj.GetValueOrDefault("nonexistent");
Debug.Assert(valObj == null);

var dictInt = new Dictionary<string, int>();
int valInt = dictInt.GetValueOrDefault("nonexistent");
Debug.Assert(valInt == 0);
```

Comment: Note that users of the extension method can't tell the difference between a non-existent key and a key that exists but its value is default(T).

Comment: On a modern computer, if you call a subroutine twice in quick succession, it is unlikely to take twice as long as calling it once. This is because the CPU and caching architecture is very likely to cache a lot of the instructions and data associated with the first call, so the second call will be executed faster. On the other hand, calling twice is almost certain to take a bit longer than calling once, so there is still an advantage to eliminating the second call if possible.

Answer (score 6):

On my machine, with loads of RAM, when run in RELEASE mode (not DEBUG), `ContainsKey` equals `TryGetValue`/`try-catch` if all entries in the `Dictionary<>` are found.

`ContainsKey` outperforms them all by far when there are just a few dictionary entries not found (in my example below, set `MAXVAL` to anything larger than `ENTRIES` to have some entries missed):

**Results:**

```
Finished evaluation .... Time distribution:
Size: 000010: TryGetValue: 53,24%, ContainsKey: 1,74%, try-catch: 45,01% - Total: 2.006,00
Size: 000020: TryGetValue: 37,66%, ContainsKey: 0,53%, try-catch: 61,81% - Total: 2.443,00
Size: 000040: TryGetValue: 22,02%, ContainsKey: 0,73%, try-catch: 77,25% - Total: 7.147,00
Size: 000080: TryGetValue: 31,46%, ContainsKey: 0,42%, try-catch: 68,12% - Total: 17.793,00
Size: 000160: TryGetValue: 33,66%, ContainsKey: 0,37%, try-catch: 65,97% - Total: 36.840,00
Size: 000320: TryGetValue: 34,53%, ContainsKey: 0,39%, try-catch: 65,09% - Total: 71.059,00
Size: 000640: TryGetValue: 32,91%, ContainsKey: 0,32%, try-catch: 66,77% - Total: 141.789,00
Size: 001280: TryGetValue: 39,02%, ContainsKey: 0,35%, try-catch: 60,64% - Total: 244.657,00
Size: 002560: TryGetValue: 35,48%, ContainsKey: 0,19%, try-catch: 64,33% - Total: 420.121,00
Size: 005120: TryGetValue: 43,41%, ContainsKey: 0,24%, try-catch: 56,34% - Total: 625.969,00
Size: 010240: TryGetValue: 29,64%, ContainsKey: 0,61%, try-catch: 69,75% - Total: 1.197.242,00
Size: 020480: TryGetValue: 35,14%, ContainsKey: 0,53%, try-catch: 64,33% - Total: 2.405.821,00
Size: 040960: TryGetValue: 37,28%, ContainsKey: 0,24%, try-catch: 62,48% - Total: 4.200.839,00
Size: 081920: TryGetValue: 29,68%, ContainsKey: 0,54%, try-catch: 69,77% - Total: 8.980.230,00
```

**Here's my code:**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Diagnostics;

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                const int ENTRIES = 10000, MAXVAL = 15000, TRIALS = 100000, MULTIPLIER = 2;
                Dictionary<int, int> values = new Dictionary<int, int>();
                Random r = new Random();
                int[] lookups = new int[TRIALS];
                int val;
                List<Tuple<long, long, long>> durations = new List<Tuple<long, long, long>>(8);

                for (int i = 0;i < ENTRIES;++i) try
                    {
                        values.Add(r.Next(MAXVAL), r.Next());
                    }
                    catch { --i; }

                for (int i = 0;i < TRIALS;++i) lookups[i] = r.Next(MAXVAL);

                Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
                ConsoleColor bu = Console.ForegroundColor;

                for (int size = 10;size <= TRIALS;size *= MULTIPLIER)
                {
                    long a, b, c;

                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                    Console.WriteLine("Loop size: {0}", size);
                    Console.ForegroundColor = bu;

                    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
                    sw.Start();
                    for (int i = 0;i < size;++i) values.TryGetValue(lookups[i], out val);
                    sw.Stop();
                    Console.WriteLine("TryGetValue: {0}", a = sw.ElapsedTicks);

                    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
                    sw.Restart();
                    for (int i = 0;i < size;++i) val = values.ContainsKey(lookups[i]) ? values[lookups[i]] : default(int);
                    sw.Stop();
                    Console.WriteLine("ContainsKey: {0}", b = sw.ElapsedTicks);

                    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
                    sw.Restart();
                    for (int i = 0;i < size;++i)
                        try { val = values[lookups[i]]; }
                        catch { }
                    sw.Stop();
                    Console.WriteLine("try-catch: {0}", c = sw.ElapsedTicks);

                    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
                    Console.WriteLine();

                    durations.Add(new Tuple<long, long, long>(a, b, c));
                }

                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.WriteLine("Finished evaluation .... Time distribution:");
                Console.ForegroundColor = bu;

                val = 10;
                foreach (Tuple<long, long, long> d in durations)
                {
                    long sum = d.Item1 + d.Item2 + d.Item3;

                    Console.WriteLine("Size: {0:D6}:", val);
                    Console.WriteLine("TryGetValue: {0:P2}, ContainsKey: {1:P2}, try-catch: {2:P2} - Total: {3:N}", (decimal)d.Item1 / sum, (decimal)d.Item2 / sum, (decimal)d.Item3 / sum, sum);
                    val *= MULTIPLIER;
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I feel like something fishy is going on here. I wonder if the optimizer might be removing or simplifying your ContainsKey() checks due to the fact that you never use the retrieved value.

Comment: It just can't. ContainsKey() is in a compiled DLL. The optimizer doesn't know anything about what ContainsKey() actually does. It might cause side effects, so it has to be called and cannot be abridged.

Comment: Something is bogus here. The fact is that examining the .NET code shows that ContainsKey, TryGetValue, and this[] all call the same internal code, so TryGetValue is faster than ContainsKey + this[] when the entry exists.

Answer (score 5):

Making a quick test program, there is definately an improvement using TryGetValue with 1 million items in a dictionary.

**Results:**

ContainsKey + Item for 1000000 hits: 45ms

TryGetValue for 1000000 hits: 26ms

Here is the test app:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const int size = 1000000;

    var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        dict.Add(i, i.ToString());
    }

    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    string result;

    sw.Start();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (dict.ContainsKey(i))
            result = dict[i];
    }

    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("ContainsKey + Item for {0} hits: {1}ms", size, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    sw.Reset();
    sw.Start();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        dict.TryGetValue(i, out result);
    }

    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("TryGetValue for {0} hits: {1}ms", size, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to get out the value from the dictionary, the TryGetValue(key, out value) is the best option, but if you're checking for the presence of the key, for a new insertion, without overwriting old keys, and only with that scope, ContainsKey(key) is the best option, benchmark can confirm this:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;

namespace benchmark
{
class Program
{
    public static Random m_Rand = new Random();
    public static Dictionary<int, int> testdict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    public static Hashtable testhash = new Hashtable();

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Adding elements into hashtable...");
        Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++)
            testhash[i]=m_Rand.Next();
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Done in {0:F4} -- pause....", watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
        Thread.Sleep(4000);
        Console.WriteLine("Adding elements into dictionary...");
        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++)
            testdict[i]=m_Rand.Next();
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Done in {0:F4} -- pause....", watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
        Thread.Sleep(4000);

        Console.WriteLine("Finding the first free number for insertion");
        Console.WriteLine("First method: ContainsKey");
        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        int intero=0;
        while (testdict.ContainsKey(intero))
        {
            intero++;
        }
        testdict.Add(intero, m_Rand.Next());
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Done in {0:F4} -- added value {1} in dictionary -- pause....", watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds, intero);
        Thread.Sleep(4000);
        Console.WriteLine("Second method: TryGetValue");
        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        intero=0;
        int result=0;
        while(testdict.TryGetValue(intero, out result))
        {
            intero++;
        }
        testdict.Add(intero, m_Rand.Next());
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Done in {0:F4} -- added value {1} in dictionary -- pause....", watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds, intero);
        Thread.Sleep(4000);
        Console.WriteLine("Test hashtable");
        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        intero=0;
        while(testhash.Contains(intero))
        {
            intero++;
        }
        testhash.Add(intero, m_Rand.Next());
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Done in {0:F4} -- added value {1} into hashtable -- pause....", watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds, intero);
        Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
}
```

This is a true Example, I have a service that for each "Item" created, it associates a progressive number, this number, each time you create a new item, must be found free, if you delete an Item, the free number becomes free, of course this is not optimized, since I have a static var that caches the current number, but in case you end all the numbers, you can re-begin from 0 to UInt32.MaxValue

Test executed:
Adding elements into hashtable...
Done in 0,5908 -- pause....
Adding elements into dictionary...
Done in 0,2679 -- pause....
Finding the first free number for insertion
First method: ContainsKey
Done in 0,0561 --  added value 1000000 in dictionary -- pause....
Second method: TryGetValue
Done in 0,0643 -- added value 1000001 in dictionary -- pause....
Test hashtable
Done in 0,3015 -- added value 1000000 into hashtable -- pause....
Press any key to continue . .

If some of you may be asking if the ContainsKeys could have an advantage, I've even tried inverting the TryGetValue with Contains key, the result is the same.

So, for me, with a final consideration, it all depends on the way the program behaves.