# Linq in dictionary collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have collection of dictionaries.

```
public class Bills
    {
        public Dictionary<string, string> billList { get; set; }
    }
```

From the list of instances of this class 'Bill' `List<Bills> allBills`, how would I get all the records where key equals 'User' and name equals 'Nick'

Comment: Please show your current approach and tell us what exactly is the problem with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of the other answers leverage the lookup-speed of the dictionary:

```
var matches = allBills
        .Where(dict => dict.billList.ContainsKey("User"))
        .Where(dict => dict.billList["User"] == "Nick");
```

Comment: Better than mine, +1 :)

Comment: why not `.Where(dict => { string name; return dict.billList.TryGetValue("User", out name) && name == "Nick"; });`

Only doing the dictionary lookup once then

Comment: Yeah - could do that - pretty-sure behind the scenes 'trygetvalue' that it's doing the exact same thing - and I think this is more readable.

Comment: @AndrasZoltan - I'm wrong. TryGetValue is faster: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382681/what-is-more-efficient-dictionary-trygetvalue-or-containskeyitem

Answer (score 1):

```
string key = "User";
string name = "Bill";

if (billList.ContainsKey(key))
{
    string result = billList[key];
    if (result == name)
        return result;
}
return null; // key and names did not match
```

A Dictionary will never have more than ***one*** occurence of the same key, so I wonder if you shouldn't be using a `Dictionary<string, Bill>` instead, in which case the code would look more like this:

```
return billList.Where(kvPair => kvPair.Value.Key == key &&
                                kvPair.Value.Name == name).Select(kvPair => kvPair.Value);
```

This code assumes that the `Bill` class contains a `Key` and a `Name` field.