# Dictionary error "KeyNotFound" when accessing my accessors

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am getting a

```
'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

when i run my code, everthing seems to be fine, i have been unable to find the bug.  Here is path of my class caling my get/set

```
   foreach (Tran transaction in transactions)
        {
            Account sAcc = items[transaction.ID1];//getting error here
            Account dAcc = items[transaction.ID2];
            decimal tempResult = sAcc.Money - transaction.Amount;
            foreach (char s in sAcc.BorP)
                Console.WriteLine(s);
```

And here is my get/set class

```
 public class Tran
{
    public int ID1 { get; set; }
    public int ID2 { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

It was running before and i ran some more test and i keep getting this error and dont know what could be causing int. Thanks for you help

Comment: `KeyNotFound` means that the `items` dictionary doesn't have an entry for `transaction.ID1`.

Comment: check if key exists first before trying to access it

Comment: Use `if itemsContainsKey(transaction.ID1)` before `items[transaction.ID1]`

Comment: @T.S. using `TryGetValue` is almost certainly preferable in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `TryGetValue` method of the dictionary.

Here is a sample code of using

```
object result; // Un-Initialized instance result
myCollection.TryGetValue("Test", out result); // If the key exists the method will out the value
```

Grabbed from another SO post.

From MSDN's entry on [Dictionary.TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx) Method:

> This method combines the functionality of the ContainsKey method and
>   the Item property.
>
> If the key is not found, then the value parameter gets the appropriate
>   default value for the value type TValue; for example, 0 (zero) for
>   integer types, false for Boolean types, and null for reference types.
>
> Use the TryGetValue method if your code frequently attempts to access
>   keys that are not in the dictionary. Using this method is more
>   efficient than catching the KeyNotFoundException thrown by the Item
>   property.
>
> This method approaches an O(1) operation.

Also reference in this post to lookup the performance of `Indexer` vs `TryGetValue`

[What is more efficient: Dictionary TryGetValue or ContainsKey+Item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382681/what-is-more-efficient-dictionary-trygetvalue-or-containskeyitem)

Answer (score -2):

The issue you are having is that the items you are trying to read from the items array don't exist.

Use either

```
if (items.ContainsKey(transaction.ID1) && items.ContainsKey(transaction.ID2))
{
  // Your code.
} else {
  // Signal an error.
}
```

Or if you have a default account class that you want to use when the transactions do not exist you could use something like this.

```
if (!items.TryGetValue(transaction.ID1, out sAcc))
  items.Add(transaction.ID1, sAcc = new Account);
if (!items.TryGetValue(transaction.ID2, out dAcc))
  items.Add(transaction.ID2, dAcc = new Account);
// Your code.
```

Otherwise if the transaction ID:s should always be in item the problem with your code is likely outside of the code snippets you shared here. I would check what the ID:s are you are trying to look up and do a sanity check.

Comment: Your code is invalid for multiple reasons: **a)** `TryGetKey` only exists for `ImmutableSortedDictionary` which the OP is almost certainly not using **b)** the syntax `items.Add(transaction.ID1, sAcc = new Account)` is invalid C# syntax on multiple levels. (`=` syntax in a method invocation does not exist and `new Account` is invalid without either `()` or `{}`) **c)** The OP almost certainly wants the value -- ergo `TryGetValue`.

Comment: Why don't just use TyGetValue?

Comment: Sorry, I did mess up the TryGetKey vs TryGetValue. The assignments work fine though as written. I use this pattern all the time.