# How do I convert ContainsKey to TryGetValue

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im trying to figure out to convert the following statement to a trygetvalue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
filters.ContainsKey("companyCode") ? filters["companyCode"] : string.Empty;
```

I have code that I inherited that has about 25 of these that builds one query statement.

Comment: What C# version are you using?

Comment: Why? That code will work...

Comment: Because it impacts performance twice @MikeMcCaughan

Comment: @PatrickHofman Seems like micro-optimization, but I'll take your word for it.

Comment: What is faster? Walking a dictionary twice or once, the answer is easy. How it affects performance depends on the number of calls. @MikeMcCaughan

Comment: Im trying to do it for a performance gain. This gets called a good bit by our customers. Also, also there 25 just like it.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Sure. I'm not disagreeing with you, and I think your answer is helpful. But there are costs and risks to these kinds of refactors, right?

Comment: @DanWilson Getting the value by index calls `FindEntry()` again, whereas `TryGetValue` does not. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382681/what-is-more-efficient-dictionary-trygetvalue-or-containskeyitem)

Comment: hardkoded, Im using version 6.

Answer (score 6):

You have to create an `if` statement where you assign the default in case the filter wasn't found:

For C# 7:

```
if (!filters.TryGetValue("companyCode", out string value))
    value = string.Empty;
```

And pre-C# 7:

```
string value;

if (!filters.TryGetValue("companyCode", out value))
    value = string.Empty;
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I just couldn't see it.

Comment: Why an `if` statement and not a ternary?

Comment: Because for beginner programmers this code is clearer. Functionally it wouldn't matter which to pick @maccettura.

Comment: @maccettura What code would be in the `true` block of a ternary operation where `TryGetValue` is the condition? Seems like a redundant assignment would have to happen.

Comment: @RufusL See Tim's answer: `string result = filters.TryGetValue("companyCode", out string code) ? code : string.Empty;`

Comment: @maccettura Yeah, sorry, I meant why would that be better? You have an additional assignment operation in the `true` case. Just curious.

Comment: @RufusL I wouldnt say a ternary is better, I just personally thought it was cleaner.  You have a solid point about the extra assignment though.

Answer (score 4):

With C#7 you can use this one liner:

```
string result = filters.TryGetValue("companyCode", out string code) ? code : string.Empty;
```

If you can't use inline `out` variables you need two lines:

```
string code;
string result = filters.TryGetValue("companyCode", out code) ? code : string.Empty;
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim!  Perfect!