# Append a value in dictionary .net

Tags: c#, .net

I want to append a string value in my dictionary in .net however I couldn't find an information about it for .net. Here is my dictionary which is set already with key-value pairs:

```
Dictionary<int, string> mydict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

I want to **append** new strings into existing ones in values.

For example: If we have <1,A> pair I want to append it to <1,AB>. Does anybody know a way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps you actually need a `Dictionary<int, List<string>>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I am not sure what you trying to do, but let me guess: if you have key which exists, you want to append to the corresponding value, if not, insert new key-value pair? If so, see code bloew:

```
var key = 1;
var val = "new value to append";
if (myDict.CotainsKey(key))
{
    myDict[key] += val;
}
else
{
    myDict.Add(key, val);
}
```

Comment: I see, I was looking for a LINQ way but thank you

Comment: @BB LINQ is for querying, not for manipulating data

Comment: Please use `TryGetValue` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382681 you will save a look-up in the dictionary if the key is already there.

Comment: Here is your one-liner: `myDict[key] = (myDict.TryGetValue(key, out var s) ? s : "") + val;`