# In latest C# versions, is there a more succinct way to access dictionary keys?

Tags: c#

I'm use to having a dictionary like the following

```
Dictionary<int, int> interestCountsDict = ( ...
```

and then, to get a value out of it that may or may not exist, have code like this

```
session.InterestCount = interestCountsDict.ContainsKey(session.Id)
                        ? interestCountsDict[session.Id]
                        : 0;
```

With all the improvements to C#, is there a better way to do this without having to call ContainsKey first?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382681/what-is-more-efficient-dictionary-trygetvalue-or-containskeyitem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since .NET Core 2.0 and .NET Standard 2.1, there is [CollectionExtensions.GetValueOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.collectionextensions.getvalueordefault?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_CollectionExtensions_GetValueOrDefault__2_System_Collections_Generic_IReadOnlyDictionary___0___1____0___1_) which does exactly what you need.

Comment: https://source.dot.net/#System.Collections/System/Collections/Generic/CollectionExtensions.cs,36e0c75545760030

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TryGetValue` which return the value for the key, if it exists, or it will return `default(T)`, for the `out` parameter:

```c#
interestCountsDict.TryGetValue(session.Id, out var interestCount);
session.InterestCount = interestCount;
```

Per the comment, the class property can't be an out variable. Instead you can inline a new variable with `out var interestCount` then assign its value to your class property.

Comment: This is not legal if `session.InterestCount` is a property, which it likely is. An intermediate local temporary would still be needed, though it can be declared inline (`out int interestCount`).

Comment: Thanks for that, I obviously didn't think about that. I updated the answer.