# Compact dictionary key lookup

Tags: c#

Is there a way to write this more compact ?

```
return _searchRedirectionMap.ContainsKey(query) ? _searchRedirectionMap[query] : "";
```

Givent that `_searchRedirectionMap` is defined as a `IDictionary<string,string>`

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601477/dictionary-returning-a-default-value-if-the-key-does-not-exist

Comment: Did you manage to answer your question @Roman? :)

Answer (score 6):

You could write an extension method on `IDictionary` that utilizes the [`TryGetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx) method:

```
public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> source, TKey key, TValue defaultValue)
{
    TValue outValue;
    if (source.TryGetValue(key, outValue))
    {
        return outValue;
    }

    return defaultValue;
}
```

and then you could use it like this:

```
return _searchRedirectionMap.GetValueOrDefault(query, string.Empty);
```

Comment: Its really a shame something like this isnt defined in ``IDictionary<TKey, TValue>``, as this would make some if-else-constructs obsolete. Which in turn makes the code more readable in most cases...

Comment: Well this is a bit specific (off the top of my head, I can't think of a bit of code in my projects that would use a default value if it wasn't in the dictionary; usually if it's not there I need to do something completely different) and has its performance drawbacks as `defaultValue` must be obtained/executed/resolved and passed into the method even if the dictionary does actually contain the key. But that's what extension methods are for: if you need that kind of method because you use it a lot? No problem! I just think it's debatable that it should be in the BCL.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Actually, a pattern that is fairly useful is a dictionary that inserts a default value for a missing key when it's first accessed, which avoids the default being recreated more often than necessary. (E.g. to do a frequency count.) Not sure if there's a case to be made for this to be in the BCL, but for the sake of a sane API you'd want a separate class for this instead of an extension.

Comment: @millimoose: I can see that as viable, perhaps if you provide a fixed value as part of the constructor.  But a method that _gets_ a value _or_ a default value (without inserting that value into that key) and then use it frequently in the consuming code seems a bit too context-specific to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TryGetValue` method but it will return null for `string` type:

```
_searchRedirectionMap.TryGetValue(key, out value);
```

Documentation: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx)

Comment: It doesnt return ``null`` if the key doesnt exist but rather doesnt modify the ``out`` parameter

Comment: @PhilipDaubmeier wrong, it returns default value for given type, which is `null` for `string`. Check the link in my answer

Comment: @PhilipDaubmeier It does return `null` (`value = default(TValue)`, so `null` in case of `string`), because out parameters must be assigned a value before the method returns.

Comment: Ooooh right... shame on me, I confused ``out`` with ``ref`` parameters