# Frequency table with zero counts for all values

Tags: c#, .net, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dictionary returning a default value if the key does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601477/dictionary-returning-a-default-value-if-the-key-does-not-exist)

I have a string that contains only digits. I'm interested in generating a frequency table of the digits. Here's an example string:

```
var candidate = "424256";
```

This code works, but it throws a `KeyNotFound` exception if I look up a digit that's not in the string:

```
var frequencyTable = candidate
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Which yields:

```
Key Count
4   2 
2   2 
5   1 
6   1
```

So, I used this code, which works:

```
var frequencyTable = (candidate + "1234567890")
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count() - 1);
```

However, in other use cases, I don't want to have to specify all the possible key values.

Is there an elegant way of inserting 0-count records into the `frequencyTable` dictionary without resorting to creating a custom collection with this behavior, such as this?

```
public class FrequencyTable<K> : Dictionary<K, int>
{
  public FrequencyTable(IDictionary<K, int> dictionary) 
    : base(dictionary)
  { }

  public new int this[K index]
  {
    get
    {
        if (ContainsKey(index))
            return base[index];
        return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Jon Skeet already answered this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601477/dictionary-returning-a-default-value-if-the-key-does-not-exist

Comment: Thank you, his TryGetValueOrDefault method is an interesting possibility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not *somehow* specify all possible key values, your dictionary will not contain an entry for such keys.

Rather than storing zero counts, you may wish to use

```
Dictionary.TryGetValue(...)
```

to test the existence of the key before trying to access it.  If TryGetValue returns false, simply return 0.

You could easily wrap that in an extension method (rather than creating a custom collection).

```
static public class Extensions
{
    static public int GetFrequencyCount<K>(this Dictionary<K, int> counts, K value)
    {
        int result;
        if (counts.TryGetValue(value, out result))
        {
            return result;
        }
        else return 0;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Dictionary<char, int> counts = new Dictionary<char, int>();
counts.Add('1', 42);
int count = counts.GetFrequencyCount<char>('1');
```

Comment: This code does work as written.

Comment: @neontapir: I'm in front of VS now and confirmed that the code does work.  I extended the code to show how to add it to an extension method, and show how to use the code.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a pattern for all the possible keys, you can use `Enumerable.Range` (or a `for` loop) to generate 0-value keys as a base table, then left join in the frequency data to populate the relevant values:

```
// test value
var candidate = "424256";

// generate base table of all possible keys
var baseTable = Enumerable.Range('0', '9' - '0' + 1).Select(e => (char)e);

// generate freqTable
var freqTable = candidate.ToCharArray().GroupBy (c => c);

// left join frequency table results to base table
var result =
    from b in baseTable
    join f in freqTable on b equals f.Key into gj
    from subFreq in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { Key = b, Value = (subFreq == null) ? 0 : subFreq.Count() };

// convert final result into dictionary
var dict = result.ToDictionary(r => r.Key, r => r.Value);
```

Sample result:

```
Key Value
0   0
1   0
2   2 
3   0
4   2
5   1
6   1
7   0
8   0
9   0
```

Comment: Allocating storage for keys that may have a 0 count is not space efficient (though it may or may not be more time efficient depending on the specific use cases).

Comment: @EricJ.: Agreed.  This solution should definitely not be used when the values are sparsely populated among the set of possible keys.