# Is there a built-in generic interface with covariant type parameter returned by an indexer?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, covariance, indexer

In this thread

[How to get null instead of the KeyNotFoundException accessing Dictionary value by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150508/how-to-get-null-instead-of-the-keynotfoundexception-accessing-dictionary-value-b)

in my own answer I used explicit interface implementation to change the basic dictionary indexer behaviour not to throw `KeyNotFoundException` if the key was not present in the dictionary (since it was convinient for me to obtain `null` in such a case right inline).

Here it is:

```
public interface INullValueDictionary<T, U>
    where U : class
{
    U this[T key] { get; }
}

public class NullValueDictionary<T, U> : Dictionary<T, U>, INullValueDictionary<T, U>
    where U : class
{
    U INullValueDictionary<T, U>.this[T key]
    {
        get
        {
            if (ContainsKey(key))
                return this[key];
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Since in a real application I had a list of dictionaries, I needed a way to access the dictionaries from the collection as an interface. I used simple `int` indexer to acess each element of the list.

```
var list = new List<NullValueDictionary<string, string>>();
int index = 0;
//...
list[index]["somekey"] = "somevalue";
```

The easiest thing was to do something like this:

```
var idict = (INullValueDictionary<string, string>)list[index];
string value = idict["somekey"];
```

The question raised when I decided to try to use covariance feature to have a collection of interfaces to use instead. So I needed an interface with covariant type parameter for the cast to work. The 1st thing that came to my mind was `IEnumerable<T>`, so the code would look like this:

```
IEnumerable<INullValueDictionary<string, string>> ilist = list;
string value = ilist.ElementAt(index)["somekey"];
```

Not that nice at all, besides `ElementAt` instead of an indexer is way worse.
The indexer for `List<T>` is defined in `IList<T>`, and `T` there is not covariant.

What was I to do? I decided to write my own:

```
public interface IIndexedEnumerable<out T>
{
    T this[int index] { get; }
}

public class ExtendedList<T> : List<T>, IIndexedEnumerable<T>
{

}
```

Well, few lines of code (I don't even need to write anything in `ExtendedList<T>`), and it works as I wanted:

```
var elist = new ExtendedList<NullValueDictionary<string, string>>();
IIndexedEnumerable<INullValueDictionary<string, string>> ielist = elist;
int index = 0;
//...
elist[index]["somekey"] = "somevalue";
string value = ielist[index]["somekey"];
```

Finally the question: can this covariant cast be somehow achieved without creating an extra collection?

Comment: Why using ElementAt(index) is way worse for you? IEnumerable checks if underlying collection implemented ICollection - if it does, it uses it's indexer to return an element instead of enumerator, so efficiency-wise it shouldn't be that much problem?

Comment: @Ravande For one, it's way uglier - indexers are mostly syntactic sugar anyway.

Comment: what's wrong with `TryGetValue(key)`?

Comment: @Ravadre SWeko is right. However I would be greatful if you could give me some link describing the optimization you are talking about.

Comment: @SWeko could you please add more details, please?

Comment: one clarifying question - do you want `ielist[index]["somekey"]` not `elist[index]["somekey"]` in the last section?

Comment: @IlyaIvanov definitely. Thank you so much. That was a terrible typo.

Comment: I have updated a answer slightly. I know it is still not what you wanted, but at least some additional information about no limitations of casting of compatible types won't be surplus. Cheers and great question

Comment: @jgauffin read the post I linked in the very beginning of the question. In that thread I say, why `TryGetValue` is not convinient for me.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov you're wrong, saying _it's not what I wanted_. It is!

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov it's rare to have such pleasure in hearing 'you're wrong' )

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov I'll try to find a reference later, but one place you can check and be sure it does work - decompile System.Linq.Enumerable.ElementAt extension method with any c# decompiler. Interesting code that can be found:  `IList<TSource> tSources = source as IList<TSource>; if (tSources != null) { return tSources[index]; } //... Rest of code` (also, I was wrong, it's not `ICollection` but `IList<T>` which must be implemented, which is more restrictive

Comment: @Ravadre thanks for your response...I'll think all this over in a while

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try use `IReadOnlyList<T>`, which is implemented by `List<T>`.

**Note** that I've added one instance of `NullValueDictionary<string, string>` to `List`, so that you won't get `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` at `elist[index]` line.

```
IReadOnlyList<NullValueDictionary<string, string>> elist = new List<NullValueDictionary<string, string>>
                                                                    { 
                                                                        new NullValueDictionary<string, string>() 
                                                                    };
IReadOnlyList<INullValueDictionary<string, string>> ielist = elist;

int index = 0;
//...
elist[index]["somekey"] = "somevalue";
string value = elist[index]["somekey"];
```

**Edit:** I've searched for covariant interfaces and collections with indexes prior to .NET 4.5, but found none. Still I think there are a little bit easier solution, than to create separate interface - just to cast one collection to another.

```
List<INullValueDictionary<string, string>> ielist = elist.Cast<INullValueDictionary<string, string>>().ToList();
```

Or use covariance gained from arrays

```
INullValueDictionary<string, string>[] ielist = elist.ToArray()
```

LINQ has some optimization that work on whole type compatibility, so you won't iterate over sequence if those types are compatible.

Cast implementation taken from [MONO Linq](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Linq/Enumerable.cs)

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Cast<TResult> (this IEnumerable source)
{
    var actual = source as IEnumerable<TResult>;
    if (actual != null)
        return actual;

    return CreateCastIterator<TResult> (source);
}
```

Note that I have changed `INullValueDictionary<T, U>` interface to contain `set` in the property so that `ielist[index]["somekey"] = "somevalue";` will work.

```
public interface INullValueDictionary<T, U> where U : class
{
    U this[T key] { get; set; }
}
```

But again - if creating a new Interface and class is ok for you and you don't want to mess around with casts everywhere - I think it is a good solution, if you have considered at the constraints, it gives.

### In search of covariance in mscorlib

This probably won't be interesting to you, but I've just wanted to find out what Types are covariant in mscorlib assembly. By running next script I received only 17 types are covariant, 9 of which are `Func`s. I have omitted `IsCovariant` implementation, because this answer is too long even without it

```
typeof(int).Assembly.GetTypes()
                    .Where(type => type.IsGenericType)
                    .Where(type=>type.GetGenericArguments().Any(IsCovariant))
                    .Select(type => type.Name)
                    .Dump();

//Converter`2 
//IEnumerator`1 
//IEnumerable`1 
//IReadOnlyCollection`1 
//IReadOnlyList`1 
//IObservable`1 
//Indexer_Get_Delegate`1 
//GetEnumerator_Delegate`1
```

Comment: +1: this indeed would suit, but it's available since .Net Framework 4.5, while I'm limited to .Net Framework 4.

Comment: My mistake was to completely forget about simple casting, while thinking in terms of co\contrvariance. This is 100% what I needed.

Comment: Great that this solved your problem. As you can see, I've started to dig deeper into this question )

Comment: [MSDN Covariance and Contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx) artcile says _covariance and contravariance enable implicit reference conversion for array types, delegate types, and generic type arguments_. I guess this is where the clue is

Comment: Yes, but you still need to call `ToArray()`.    It becomes more simple indeed `INullValueDictionary<string, string>[] ielist = elist.ToArray()`

Comment: Well, yes. However due to I don't see any built-in collection to use convariance here, I guess, casting is appropriate enough to use for me instead of extra interface and class. Well, at least, in my current context, it's not worse