# Less wrong TryGetValue then null check syntax

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator, trygetvalue

I'm a little new to C# still... I'm finding myself reusing a specific procedure over and over. Before I go writing a helper method for personal laziness, is there a shorter or less wrong way to write this sort of statement?

```
Dictionary<string, string> data = someBigDictionary;
string createdBy;
data.TryGetValue("CreatedBy", out createdBy);
//do that for 15 other values
...
MyEntity me = new MyEntity{
    CreatedBy = createdBy ?? "Unknown",
    //set 15 other values
    ...
}
```

Essentially, set a property on an object by trying to get a value, then if it's null use a default value. I have a LOT of properties, it would be better if I could just

```
MyEntity me = new MyEntity{
    CreatedBy = TryToGetValueOrReturnNull(data, "CreatedBy") ?? "Unknown",
    ...
}
```

Again, I am perfectly capable of writing my own helper function. I'm looking for an existing native functionality or shorthand before I do so.

Comment: Is data a Dictionary?

Comment: Why not provide the default value as another parameter? You can pass in null if you want - but you can pass in "Unknown" instead.

Comment: @mjwills yes, apologies I will clarify that

Comment: @JonSkeet may well do that if I write my own... just showing an example

Comment: If you can use C# 7 - you can do this: `CreatedBy = data.TryGetValue("CreatedBy", out var value) ? value : "Unknown"`

Comment: @Evk I cannot for this application, but that sounds like a valid answer for anyone who comes by later using C# 7 so please post

Comment: IMHO it's better to leave the `CreatedBy` field blank _(dbnull)_ instead of writing a default valid _"Unknown"_ value. The UI should present "Unknown" when the `CreatedBy` field is empty. This way you can always distingues a name and _nothing_

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen valid point, but this was simply an example. The default values are varied

Comment: Helper function gives you advantage of abstraction so it eases future changes. Why are you trying to avoid it?

Comment: @AntonínLejsek I'm only trying to avoid it if there is some sort of shorthand functionality that already exists natively. I'm perfectly fine with a helper otherwise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many similar questions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2601477/5311735) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14150508/5311735)) which propose different solutions from extension methods to inheriting from dictionary and overriding indexer. However they are written before C# 7, and with C# 7 you can do this in one line:

```
CreatedBy = data.TryGetValue("CreatedBy", out var value) ? value : "Unknown"
```

Comment: It appears that this is not possible without a helper method pre-C# 7, so I'm accepting this as the best answer even though I cannot use it in my specific implementation.

Comment: It is possible, just clunky. 
string value;

MyEntity me = new MyEntity{
    CreatedBy = data.TryGetValue("CreatedBy", out value) ? value : "Unknown",
    UpdatedBy = data.TryGetValue("UpdatedBy", out value) ? value : "Unknown"
    //set 15 other values
    ...
}

Answer (score 3):

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static U TryGetValueOrDefault<T, U>(this IDictionary<T, U> dict, T key, U defaultValue)
    {
        U temp;

        if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out temp))
            return temp;

        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

then do something like:

```
Dictionary<string, string> data = someBigDictionary;
//do that for 15 other values
...
MyEntity me = new MyEntity{
    CreatedBy = data.TryGetValueOrDefault("CreatedBy", "Unknown"),
    //set 15 other values
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`TryGetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a `bool` indicating if the key was found in the dictionary. So you should use that and set the variable to the default if it was not found:

```
string createdBy;
if (!data.TryGetValue("CreatedBy", out createdBy)) createdBy="Unknown";
```